# javascript merge/sort fatal error

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

I was writing the merge sort algorithm, and in the merge helper function, I had the following comparison statement:

```
    function merge(a,b){
        var result = [];
            while(a.length && b.length){
                    result.push(a[0] < b[0] ? a.shift() : b.shift()); // you can't just grab a[0] or b[0] 
        //as it results in a fatal error.
                }
return, etc.
}
```

Why is it that when instead of 'a.shift()', I typed a[0], it resulted in a fatal error? Is it because you are doing something with something that's also in a conditional clause?

Comment: Guessing that `a[0]` doesn't remove the entry from `a` so you end up in an infinite loop that makes `result` somewhat larger than desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the documentation for [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift). It removes the first element. So if you only access a[0] and don't remove it then the while loop never exits.